# how to bind a datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, datagridview

i tried to bind a datagrid but there is a problem in binding of my datagrid..

C# code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("Source");
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Desc", Type.GetType("System.String"));


        Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();
        List<Value> lstValue = oInsurance.Category.ValueList;
        foreach (Value item in lstValue)
        {

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = item.Key.ToString();
            dr[1] = item.Value.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        grdCategory.DataSource = ds;
        grdCategory.DataMember = "Source";
        grdCategory.DataTextField = "Desc";
        grdCategory.DataValueField = "ID";
        grdCategory.DataBind();
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no question in th eabove, what is the error or problem?

Comment: be specified about the problem you facing on binding a grid

Comment: Are you using a `DataGrid` or `DataGridView`? You can't just throw both tags in there and expect people to guess.

Comment: Please revise your question to indicate the _exact_ problem you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... try to post the error that you are getting from this...

but... if you don't need the DataSet you could just do like this...

```
Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();
List<Value> lstValue = oInsurance.Category.ValueList;

grdCategory.DataSource = lstValue;
grdCategory.AutoGenerateColumns = true; //not sure that's the property
grdCategory.DataBind();
```